# Checking matching value and display at gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, gridview

I have list of all days in a month **(as GridView header)** refer to which month is selected by user which then be displayed in GridView.

**Display list of Days in a month**

```
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim col As New DataColumn
dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(0) {New DataColumn("Date")})
For i As Integer = 1 To gsTotalDD 'gsTotalDD is total of days in a month
    dt.Columns.Add(i)
Next
dt.Rows.Add("Status")
gvRptStatus.DataSource = dt
gvRptStatus.DataBind()
```

I had a table named **tblUpload** inside the database which storing data that been uploaded together with date of data uploaded.

What I am trying to do is looping through all the header value **(list of days)** and check either there is day matching with the date of data uploaded. When there is matching value, the **status** row on the code `dt.Rows.Add("Status")` will show status **done** and leave cell **empty** if no matching days found.

Example : GridView date (fist row), second header column is 1 and check with database has matching value or not. If yes then on (second row) status, at second column will display **done**.

**EDIT**

So I came up with checking the matching value like this :

```
Dim lCnn As New SqlConnection(gsConnString)
Dim lCmd As New SqlCommand
Dim lsCmd As String
Dim dt As New DataTable
Dim newDt As New DataTable
Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter
Dim dtrow As DataRow = newDt.NewRow()

lCnn.Open()
lCmd.Connection = lCnn
lsCmd = "SELECT DISTINCT DATEPART (d, [date])"
lsCmd &= " FROM dbUpload..tblUpload"
lCmd.CommandText = lsCmd
sda.SelectCommand = lCmd
sda.Fill(newDt)

dt.Columns.AddRange(New DataColumn(0) {New DataColumn("Date")})
    For i As Integer = 1 To gsTotalDD   'gsTotalDD is total of days in a month
        dt.Columns.Add(i)
        value2 = i
    For Each col As DataColumn In newDt.Columns
        value = newDt.Rows(i - 1).Item(col)
        If value = value2 Then
            MsgBox("Same value")
        End If
    Next
Next
```

By doing this, I manage to check the value but it's not the right way to do it since I wanted to set the status as **done** if got matching value or leave status **empty** if vice versa.

Thank you.

Comment: can you post your sql query that you've tried?

Comment: @SankarRaj This should be the SQL query that I will use `select distinct datepart(d, [date]) as day from dbUpload..tblUpload`

Comment: SO you want to loop through the datatable columns with resultset rows.

Comment: Do I need to do the checking and set the value of the status on run time?